# How does Google maps find my location quickly but when I use Location Manager I need to wait 40+seconds

Tags: java, android, gps, location

Is it possible to look at the algorithm used in Google maps? If not, are there any good algorithms for finding a fine location quickly?

**edit**

NickT has pointed out that google maps uses the network provider to initially get the location, and if I put my phone on airplane mode it would take google maps just as long as my application to find my location, he was right.

My question now is, how does google maps find a fairly accurate location from The network provider even though the network provider usually not very accurate. ie accuracy 1000+ meter  most of the time (for me atleast)

ps i am using the latest location API in the play services lib

Comment: If I recall correctly google maps gets a bad position from what evers available (phone masts mostly) and gets a gps fix if possible

Comment: First of all, we should see your code to understand why you need 40+ seconds to get a position.
Then, I suggest you to switch to the new Location API: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html
Never had a problem or significant delay in getting current location.

Comment: Have a look at the new [Location API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) that was introduced earlier this year. In particular, be on the lookout for the Fused Location Provider and [`LocationClient.getLastLocation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation%28%29).

Comment: As first comment by Richard points out, it uses phone masts to start with. Put your phone into airplane mode, leaving GPS on and see how quickly Google Maps gets a fix - no faster than your app I'll bet.

Comment: @NickT you are right, after putting my phone on airplane mode google maps takes an age to find my location. My question now is, since network location is not very accurate how does it get a fairly accurate location from network only initially

Comment: what is fairly acurate? how many meters offset? are you using wifi, or are connected to cell tower? city or rural region?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, how do some apps get a very quick location fix even though network and GPS information available may not be that precise:

Most devices (including Android, apple and Microsoft as far as I am aware) also use nearby WiFi spots to pinpoint your location.

They do this by regularly updating location data and nearby wifi spots from all users and hence building up a large database mapping particular WiFi networks (which are typically very short range, relatively speaking) to geographic locations.

When they want to get a quick location fix they can look at multiple inputs, e.g. the network provider masts, the GPS data and the nearest wifi networks. They do the WiFi part by seeing what Wifi network ids are in range and looking up the database they have built to map this to a location.